# In Owl-carousel, image inside parent div with border-radius and overflow hidden is not working

Tags: html, image, css, owl-carousel

I need a carousel which has rounded images. Div with border-radius and overflow hidden works fine when it is not integrated with Owl-Carousel & i want it inside Owl-Carousel. any help would be appreciated .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".testo").owlCarousel({
        items:1
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #444;
}
.wrp {
    width: 600px; 
    height: 200px; 
    position: absolute;         
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -100px; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -300px; 
    background-color: #5a5a5a; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}
.testo {
 margin: 10px 0px;
}

.img-wrap {
    width: 180px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    height: 180px; 
    border-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>My Test Document</title>
 
 <link href="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrp">
        <div class="testo">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x350&text=1st+img" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x350&text=1st+img" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I will quote: "If you are trying to hide absolute positioned elements make sure the container of those absolute positioned elements is relatively positioned."
Parent div must be relatively positioned if you want to use overflow hidden.

Add position: relative

```
.img-wrap {
  width: 180px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  margin: 0px auto; 
  height: 180px; 
  border-radius: 90px;
  position: relative;
}
```